# Create SharePoint site sharing report using PowerShell or MS Graph APIs

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to create SharePoint site sharing report using PowerShell or MS Graph APIs. We can manually download this report from site usage analytics page or I just append this URL- **_layouts/15/siteanalytics.aspx?view=19** to SharePoint site.

[image]